# Angular 5 removes (click) event on html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-cli

So, I have this code:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-link" (click)="show = !show">Toggle</a>
```

but when the code renders, HTML this is how it looks in the Dev Console

```
<a _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-link" type="button">Toggle</a>
```

I've tried it as a button and this is what I get...

```
<button _ngcontent-c5="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-link" type="button">Toggle</button>
```

Thoughts on why this is happening?

Code is from this Stackblitz link is what I'm using:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimum-angular-code-for-a-transition?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Here's my set up:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

**UPDATE**

I've written a function that works, but I'm getting undefined... here's the mini version of the code starting from the top of my .ts file:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-link" (click)="showHidePaperroll(false)">Toggle</button>
```

**.TS FILE**

This start under the constructor() {}

```
public thePaperRoll: HTMLElement;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.thePaperRoll = document.querySelector(".box") as HTMLElement;
}


showHidePaperroll(what: boolean) {
    console.log("In Show Hide paperroll");
    let paperBox: any = "";
    paperBox = document.getElementById(".box") as HTMLImageElement;

    if (what === false) {
      paperBox = this.thePaperRoll.style.opened;
      console.log("PaperBox: ", paperBox);
    } else {
      paperBox = this.thePaperRoll.style.opened;
      console.log("PaperBox: ", paperBox);
    }

}
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  background-color: #FFCC55;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: ease-in-out 500ms max-height;
}

.box.opened {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: ease-in-out 700ms max-height;
}
```

Comment: The handlers are added by Angular, just not by adding an `onclick` attribute to the rendered HTML. What's the issue here? The click events still work.

Comment: angular-cli version 1? try ng update before anything else

Comment: Angular does not render 'onclick'. Please check details in its Event Listens tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: What's not happening is that even though I copied what's in the Stackblitz example, it doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the stackbitz does NOT show your error - it's just the example from where you started? if so, what exactly means "it does not work"?

Comment: 1) To the extent you're writing *ANY* new code, you really should update your Angular and Angular/CLI (for example, to 7.1.x).  2) `<button (click)="...">` *should* work.  There's "something else" going on here...

Comment: Well, we're stuck with this angular 5 due to using Gradle 3.1 and the backend running from InteliJ.  It's MESSED UP... I'll try and install 2.0 and see if we can still work. The main issue is that the codebase is not ready to be moved to Angular 7 which is where we need to be.  Let me try that first.  What's weird, is that calling a function with (click) works fine as  wanndream stated. But doing what's in the Stackblitz for show = !show doesn't. I'm writing a small function to perform this action. Thoughts here would be great as the alternative workaround. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Oh, that Stackblitz's answer is using Angular 7 not Angular 5. I need to do a workaround for Angular 5 via a function and I think that'll help

Comment: When you get around to upgrading, I'd consider moving from IntellJ to [MS Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) ;)  As far as "show = !show" ... Q: Do you actually see a value for "show" in Dev Tools console?  Do you see any action at all (especially some kind of JS error) in Dev Tools console?

Comment: No! I see nothing for show != show. So I made a function, SEE UPDATE, and it's firing, but I need to make the hidden div show like the Stackblitz but work with a function, vice the show != show.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem regarding the Angular version. I try the code in the Stackblitz example by the below environment, it is working without any error. Angular CLI: 1.6.8, Node: 8.11.3, Angular: 5.2.5

Comment: No way!  Then my environment must be the issue... perhaps I need to put more up on my own stackblitz or here for more help.  Thoughts?